# python '__file__' is not defined

Tags: python, c, python-2.7

the situation is:

python embed in ios app (libpython2.7.a), all logic is writed by python, some api support to call though swig wrap, if the python is **py(c,o)** everything is ok but **too slow**, i want to speed up than i use cython compile to .c source than .so, it seem load but

> can't find  "__ file __" define

here is the call stack:

```
[CGPLoad.py] load from file error [Error Message:

exceptions.NameError:name '__ file __' is not defined

Traceback:

init CGPLoad (build/CGPLoad.c:3054): CGPLoad.py(# 19)

init LogInOutShell (build/LogInOutShell.c:3089): LogInOutShell.py(# 20)

init CommonToolShell (build/CommonToolShell.c:6560): CommonToolShell.py(# 19)

init GameWorld (build/GameWorld.c:2516): GameWorld.py(# 19)

init IPY_GAMEWORLD (build/IPY_GAMEWORLD.c:27700): IPY_GAMEWORLD.py(# 28)

IPY_GAMEWORLD.swig_import_helper (build/IPY_GAMEWORLD.c:4304): IPY_GAMEWORLD.py(# 18)

]
```

the python source is:

```
fp, pathname, description = imp.find_module('_IPY_GAMEWORLD', [dirname(__ file __)])
```

**what's the problem, how to fix it?**

Comment: Looks like you have spaces between `__` and `FILE`.

Comment: er... if closer it can't show the "__", it is "__file__"

Answer (score 4):

It is intended behaviour, as `__file__` is not defined for compiled executable. You should check for that case with

```
getattr(sys, 'frozen', False)
```

and act accordingly, for example:

```
if getattr(sys, 'frozen', False):
    __file__ = os.path.dirname(sys.executable)
```

Comment: thanks, i found the article   http://bugs.python.org/issue13429

Comment: it seems that the .so use the "__file__" before it init

Answer (score 1):

If you only need to get a package root path in Cython module, but `__file__` is not defined due to the Python bug http://bugs.python.org/issue13429, then you can use a simple trick by referencing `__init__.py`:

```
def get_package_root():
    from . import __file__ as initpy_file_path
    return os.path.dirname(init‌​py_file_path)
```

Comment: in python 3.6.1 this does not work either. Reports an error: ```Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 94, in init main (..\..\main.c:3617)
  File "main.py", line 6, in main.get_package_root (..\..\main.c:1237)
    super().__init__(ismain=True, uni_theme=True)
ImportError: cannot import name __file__```